# scheduling a one time request using PHP

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have a url in my own website that I want to hit at a scheduled time and once, the url will have different parameters, so for example:

```
www.mysite.com?user_id=1    ==> execute this once 5 minutes from now
www.mysite.com?user_id=2    ==> execute this once 10 minutes from now
www.mysite.com?user_id=3    ==> execute this once 15 minutes from now
www.mysite.com?user_id=4    ==> execute this once 20 minutes from now
```

How can I do this in php? I was considering to use cron job, but that seemed to be used for repeated actions, while in this case I wanted it to execute once only. Also I was considering to use sleep, however sleep blocks the current execution. Any other alternative to do this?

Comment: `I wanted it to execute once only` <-- when do you want it to execute?

Comment: @invisal like what I specified the above, at X minutes from the current time

Comment: Do you assume that you are the only visitor on the site or do others also visit the site frequently?

Comment: Well, do you mean that someone need to click on something, then those link will execute from specified time? Someone must do something to trigger those, right? It doesn't just magically decide to trigger itself.

Comment: @invisal yes exactly.. so I will manually execute www.mysite.com?user_id=4, and then from there it will propage the request on it's own to other user_id's

Comment: @whereismydipp other visitor will visit the site, but this particular url will be hidden

Comment: Do you want it to be exactly 5 minutes, 10 minutes... or a little bit off from 5 minutes is acceptable as well?

Comment: @invisal a little bit off is acceptable as well, in fact this will be a random number between 5-10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, have a text file that contains a link that you want to update with timestamp. For example:

```
1379041200 www.mysite.com?user_id=1 
1379051200 www.mysite.com?user_id=2 
1379101200 www.mysite.com?user_id=3
```

Append more link and timestamp that you want to execute into file if you want to add more link. Then have a con job that execute once every 5 minutes. The cron job will check if there is any link with timestamp smaller than current timestamp.

Comment: The con job will check if there is any link with timestamp smaller than current timestamp. =====> is this done automatically? I don't need to code anything?

Comment: Of course, you need to code something. First of all, Make your cron job to execute one of your PHP code (every 5 minutes) that read the file. Read line by line, and get timestamp of each line. Compare it with current timestamp. Then execute the link.

Comment: Gotcha.. I thought this was a built in thing from the cronjob such that when I have a text file with timestamp in front of it, it would compare with the timestamp the job was executed.

Comment: By the way this is totally a very smart and simple hack. Love it :)

Comment: @aherlambang, it does need to be file. You can also use database. Once you done execute any link, just delete record from database or remove a line from file.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a wait time parameter and put sleep at the start of you code

```
www.mysite.com?user_id=1&wait_for=300

if(isset($_GET['wait_for'])) {
    sleep($_GET['wait_for']);
}
```

This way your actual file code will be executed after a delay